# Why can't chrome storage be considered secure?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

I read a lot of stackoverflow topics to get a basic understanding of security in chrome extensions / front-end javascript. Simply everyone says its not secure to store sensitive data in chrome storage (even with encrypting its not save).

As far as I know the chrome storage runs in its own context and therefore nobody should access those variables from the outside. I understand that it's not secure if someone else sits in front of my computer and can access them. I just want to know why I can't save a password in chrome storage and send it over HTTPS to my server.

It's my extension, it's my server. It's secured with HTTPS. What are the risks to store the password in chrome.storage? If someone could explain that or could give me a good reference to read more about that topic I would be really thankful.

Comment: You are using a program (chrome) which runs on an unknown OS (could be windows, could be linux) under unknown set of privileges (could be admin, could be guest, could be some other user). In that program, that "talks" to your server over potentially insecure network (MITM), you are storing credentials using an extension you wrote. Are you 100% sure that there is 0% chance you won't install a program or get infected by a program that scans Chrome's storage and sends data around? Even if someone steals encrypted password, they can use it to log on to your server.

Comment: It's not necessarily *your* code that can be at fault for exposing data. There could be a bug in Chrome that inadvertently leaked storage details. There's probably not, it's just a matter of "it can't be compromised if it's not there"

Comment: So basically it's not secure because the PC could be infected by malware / MITM and steal my stored data?

Comment: A location is secure if you have complete control over how it handles the data (saving, reading, returning). Since you don't - it's not secure. Other programs, regardless of the fact whether you have them running, can also access that storage and retrieve your password. It's not secure unless you have fine control over who can access it, how they access it and what the authentication behind it is. Since none of these are under your control - the storage is not secure for sensitive data. Imagine if I stole your password and sent it to that server. Would it let me in?

Comment: @Mjh But how am I supposed to get a "secure" authentication for my chrome extension? The default answer for secure authentication in front end is probably Oauth(2). But because there is no redirect to the extension i can't use this. I just want to load some user information but don't know how to get them securely.

Comment: This looks like XY problem to me. Your perceived solution is to have something stored to Chrome's storage. However, what is the underlying goal? Your HTTP(S) server needs to authenticate the person using the browser? If we can deconstruct that problem, a different (and proper) solution might be presented.

Comment: I have a webpage. The user can register and login on this page. He can add specific information on this website (its used for syncing settings for cross platforms). Now there is a chrome extension who needs to load the user specific settings to perform the right.

Comment: instead of saving a password, most websites like google give you a temporary id that expires after a certain period of time.  so your browser doesn't save your password, but you can still log on to the site for some time.  Why not do that instead?

Comment: Right, so the extension effectively performs an HTTP request and authenticates as that user, correct? So why don't you use the classic methods of authenticating people? Even what @ThouArtAmazing said is perfectly ok - a temporary token that identifies the user. You can even encrypt this token with information such as IP + browser fingerprint + user_id and before your code runs on the server.

Comment: sorry bit this convo doesnt make much sense. the fears of storing a password in storage i think are unfounded. the only way for someone to access it would be a chrome bug that somehow leaks that to another website, or malware in the pc. both scenarios can happen to ANY program running on the pc that stores a password on the disk. saying to instead use tokens isnt secure in that case either as stealing a refresh token stored by chrome gives access to anyone just like a password (except that it protects on password reuse attacks)

Comment: Thanks Zig Mandel! That was exactly what I was thinking about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/